# how to get Field dependency in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller, field-dependencies

This is My visualforce page and Controller to get Field Dependency, Here I am Getting All the Values but Dependency is Not Working

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >Country</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList id="countries" value="{!selectedCountry}" size="1" style="width:150px">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!Country}"/><apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="out" status="status"/>
    </apex:selectList></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel >City</apex:outputLabel>
    <apex:selectList id="City" value="{!selectedCity}" size="1" style="width:150px">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!City}"/><apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="out" status="status"/>
    </apex:selectList></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
```

Apex code:

```
Country = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = University__c.Country__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> coun = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        Country.add(new SelectOption('None', '--None--')); 
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry p : coun)
        {
        Country.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getValue())); 
        }

        //multipicklist values for city
        City = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult15 = University__c.City__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> cit = fieldResult15.getPicklistValues();
        City.add(new SelectOption('None', '--None--')); 
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry p15 : cit)
        {
        City.add(new SelectOption(p15.getValue(), p15.getValue())); 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `apex:inputField` tags that creates dependencies automatically:

Apex:

```
public University__c university { get; set; }

public YourClass(){
    university = new University__c();
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:iputfield value="{!university.Country__c}" />
    <apex:iputfield value="{!university.City__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Additionaly you can read this great topic: [Adding Dependent Fields to a Page](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm)

Comment: I have created search functionality as of now it is searching for country ,state and city .Above you mention input field to get values it is working fine but i need to pass this value in soql query to search and these picklist's should be dependent to each other.

Comment: @user5644 These picklist's are dependent to each other automatically because you will access an sObject directly ("university"). And it is for sure not a problem to use these merge fields in the SOQL query like this: `where Country__c = :university.Country__c`